# How to make @Html.TextBox hidden and of date type at the same time?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I need to hide textbox of type=date. Later I want to show this textbox again using some js. The issue is how I can use type=date and type=hidden at the same time in html helper? I can't add another 'type' attribute because an error shows up. The below is wrong:

```
@Html.TextBox("dateFrom", null, new { @type = "date", @type = "hidden", @class = "form-control datepicker"})
```

Is it possible to hide this datepicker using hidden attribute?

Comment: `@type = "date", hidden = "hidden"`?

Comment: yes, it works, thank you very much!